# How to extract png images from pdf stream using c++

Tags: pdf, stream, extract, png

[image]I opened a pdf file which has a png image with notepad,I can find the stream of png image,likes the attached file,I studied the png format and knew a png image was constructed at least 4 parts:PNG Signature、IHDR chunk、IDAT chunks、IEND chunk,it's easy to process PNG Signature、IHDR chunk、IEND chunk and copy the stream data as IDAT chunk when create a png image,then the created png image looks like gibberish.So,I think whether I need to decompress that stream or do others,does anyone can help me?

Look at the attached image,image 1 is the image before it was insertted into a pdf file,image 2 is the image that manully extracted from pdf and the CRC is computed by C program.There is a big difference between the two images.I want to get the effect as image 1,could anyone know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: PDF doesn't support PNG images. The image data in a PDF file can be JPEG (JFIF), JPEG-2000, JBIG2 or simply a stream of bytes representing the image sample data (pixels). The image you have here is simply a stream of bytes, compressed with the Flate filter. (it also has a separate Soft mask).

Comment: I tried mupdf and could extract images,but I want to extract images without using pdf library.

Answer (score 0):

You have an RGB 8 bits per component image here, with a soft mask.

Disregarding the soft mask, you can extract the image as a PNG without decompression like this:

1. Write the PNG file signature
2. Write the PNG IHDR chunk using the width, height and bit depth. Write its CRC.
3. Write an IDAT chunk with the FlateDecode data from the PDF. The FlateDecode data is not the whole IDAT chunk: you need to top and tail it with "IHDR", length and CRC as normal.
4. Write the IEND chunk

Taking account of the soft mask will probably involve decompressing the main stream and SMask stream, combining them and then recompressing, so as to include an alpha channel.

Comment: No, that won't work. PNG image data requires a filter byte at the start of each row. The flate-compressed data is just the pixels.

Comment: You are right, of course. I was getting confused with the other direction, PNG to PDF, which can be done by setting appropriate "DecodeParms" in the PDF based on the PNG filter. For example: `<</Height 220/Width 346/DecodeParms<</Predictor 15/Columns 346/Colors 3/BitsPerComponent 8>>/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/BitsPerComponent 8/Subtype/Image/Filter/FlateDecode/Length 21235>>`

Comment: Hi Mark Adler,thanks for your reply,do you know how to transform flate-compressed data of pdf image stream to IDAT chunk of png